# Why can't I enter my employer?

Tags: facebook, profile

I have created a brand/business page and I'd like to include is as my employment on my personal account and I keep getting 'The employer you have entered is invalid.' Why is this? Shouldn't my brand page show up in the records? Why can't I enter whatever employer I'd like?

Comment: Is this a programming question? It sounds more like a "how do I use facebook" question, or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the Facebook 'intellisense'/'auto-complete' isn't very responsive/exhaustive. In the employer field, try typing in the EXACT name of your Facebook page and hit 'enter'. It should show up.